# Adding a JScrollPane component to a JTable column

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I'm trying to add scrolling capabilities to a certain column in my JTable.  I've implemented a custom TableCellRenderer component and I can see the scroll pane inside the table just fine, but I am not able to scroll it.  I've tried implementing TableCellEditor as well and didn't have any luck.

```
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable arg0, Object arg1,
        boolean arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
    return scrollPane;
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to make those cells which contain a scrollPane scrollable?

Comment: I've never tried a JScrollPane but I have done similar with JButton table cell editors.  How does your code handle starting editing and stopping editing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With TableCellRenderer it's not possible to add any scrolling behaviour, as it does not receive any events and only draws the component.
It is possible - however - to accomplish this by using a custom TableCellEditor with *getTableCellEditor* being:

```
public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean   isSelected, int row, int column) {
    JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
    area.setLineWrap(true);
    area.setText((String) value);

    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(area);

    return pane;
}
```

Additionally, you have to control the editing behaviour of your CellEditor. To make the cell editable and scrollable always, *isCellEditable* should look like this:

```
public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent) {
    return true;
}
```

Personally, I find this solution to be more of a hack than anything, though.
Also, this should only be for testing. You really do have to implement a better editing behaviour in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the isCellEditable method.  Curious though, why do you consider this a hack?

Comment: Well, I guess 'hack' is the wrong word. I just don't like the `return true` statement as it overrides anything and does not take the EventObject `anEvent` into consideration, for example. But, if the cell really should be editable at all times, this is the way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

A Renderer just paints the cells.  I believe you need to implement a `TableCellEditor` to scroll.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, consider placing a single scroll pane in a separate container and updating it's view in your selection listener.