# Scrolling inside a JTable cell in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, scrollbar, jscrollpane

I have a table each cell contains a image. if the image size is more than row height, I have added `JScrollPane`.  Now when I run the application, scroll is visible in each cell but I'm not able to scroll it.

How can I do it?

Below is the code I'm using to add scroll pane.

Any sample code will be appreciated.

```
     private final JTable table = new JTable(model)

    {

    @Override public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer tcr, int      row, int column) 

    {
         Component c = super.prepareRenderer(tcr, row, column);
         if(isRowSelected(row))              
         {
             c.setForeground(getSelectionForeground());
             c.setBackground(getSelectionBackground());             
         }             
       else{
             c.setForeground(getForeground());
             c.setBackground((row%2==0)?evenColor:getBackground());
         }
         JScrollPane _pane=new JScrollPane(c);
         table.setRowHeight(100);
         return _pane;
     }
};
```

Comment: Seems like the making of an unusable GUI, when you expect the user to scroll in order to see the content of table cells.

Comment: may be following links will helpful to you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388453/adding-a-jscrollpane-component-to-a-jtable-column

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395554/scrollable-cells-in-jtable

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on your jscrollpane
2. Properties
3. HOrizontal scrollbarpolicy = always
4. Vertical scrollbarpolicy = always

To be able to scroll
Right Click on Jtable
Autocreatecolumnfrommodel =false(deactivaded)

Comment: maybe you dont need to scroll, you need change the height of every row with the mouse

Comment: When you have lot of data you will see the scroll bar

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to set the focus on the cell (so you can use the inside scroll pane), you can get it through "edit mode":

1. Create a custom cell editor:

   ```
        public class MyCustomCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor{
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table,Object value,boolean isSelected,int row,int column) {

                    JScrollPane your_custom_panel=new JScrollPane();
                    return your_custom_panel; // your _pane
        }

        @Override
        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            return null;
        }
   ```
2. Set it on your table:

   ```
        table.setDefaultEditor(MyCustomCellValueType.class,new MyCustomCellEditor());
   ```

Now you only need to manage how to enter in "edit mode" and you should be able to scroll inside the cell.