# Displaying long text in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

By default, in a JTable cell, Strings are displayed on a single line, and their ends are replaced by " ... " if their length exceeds the current width of the cell.
I am looking for a simple way to display entirely a long text in a JTable cell, on multiple lines when it is necessary. So basically I want the cell's width and height to adapt automatically so that any String is fully displayed :

```
=============================
| Col1 | Col2 | This is some|
|      |      | very long   |
|      |      | text!       |
=============================
```

I did some research but what I found was eitheir ineffective or very complicated compared with the simplificty of the feature.

Does anyone have a simple solution for this ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `very complicated compared with the simplificty of the feature.` - its complicated because it is not as simple as you think. A simple solution would be to display a tooltip for the cell.

Comment: Take a look at [Adding a JScrollPane component to a JTable column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388453/adding-a-jscrollpane-component-to-a-jtable-column).

Comment: Agreed with camickr, you would need to be able to calculate the row size of each row based on the contents of each cell in the given row, this is very complicated and time consuming and would greatly effect the performance of the table, even over a small data set

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc While a neat solution, the problem I would have with it is the fact that I would need to get the cell into edit mode to make it work (I couldn't hover my mouse over it and mouse wheel for example)